# Including Key in d3 Data Map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to set a key on a d3 map, but it's not recognising my key function after the object, with the key still 0,1,2 etc. What am I doing wrong?

```
d3.csv("data/words.csv").then(function(data) {
    // clean data
    const formattedData = data.map(yearWord => {
        //yearWord.key = yearWord.year + ":" + yearWord.word
        yearWord.count = Number(yearWord.count)
        return yearWord
    }, function(d) { return d.year + ":" + d.word; })
```

Comment: What data structure are you ultimately trying to achieve? As Rueben Helsloot notes, d3.map and array.map are different functions, and neither use a key function. `d3.csv` does use an init function, but it's hard to answer this question without clarification.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a [`d3.map`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/#map), but [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), there is no key function. You could make your data into an object:

```js
data.reduce((obj, {year, word, count }) => {
    obj[`${year}:${word}`] = Number(count);
}, {});
```

This would return an object of structure `{ "2020:pandemic": 9001 }`. Then you could access all keys using `Object.keys(myObject)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a key value like this:

```js
let map = d3.map({"Foo": 5, "Bar": 10, "Baz": 15});
myKeys = map.keys();
console.log(myKeys);
```

So you may be able to just pass the `data` value to the `d3.map()` method but it may need some more setup depending on the `data` format.